# How to use v-model with multiple checkboxes generated by v-for?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Don't know how to use `v-model` on input checkbox type from a loop of a nested element.

I have successfully used a select/dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" v-model="slide.filterCat">
    <option :value="item.category" v-for="(item,index) in categories.elCats" :key="index">{{item.category}}</option>
</select>
```

It returns the item and models it correctly when updated,
however I would need to offer several options that can be selected and trying to use checkboxes instead.
The loop works fine and all labels and checkboxes are being shown correctly.
But I have no idea on how I can use simple v-model here.
I have used a method that checks if value is in array and if so to return true,
which works by using binding on `:checked`

```
:checked="isInCategoryList(item.category, slide.filterCat)
```

and the method:

```
isInCategoryList(curEl, list){
    console.log(curEl);
    console.log(list);
    return list.includes(curEl ) ? true : false
},
```

But it logs an insane amount, which makes me think the approach is definitely not the correct one, for every event (mouseover,...) it keeps logging data.

And this snippet simply didn't work:

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in categories.elCats" :key="index">
    <label>{{item.category}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" :value="item.category"
    v-model="slide.filterCat">
</div>
```

Any guidance please...

Comment: What is the type of `slide.filterCat` ?

Comment: @MichalLevý typeof string. And the array contains objects.

Comment: Use the last snipet and change the type of `slide.filterCat` to array ('[]') - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: @MichalLevý
Aaah, jeeez.
If you add as an answer I will accept it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple checkboxes (as well as `<select multiple>`) requires the `v-model` argument to be an array...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      categories: [{
          name: 'Category A',
          value: 'A'
        },
        {
          name: 'Category B',
          value: 'B'
        },
        {
          name: 'Category C',
          value: 'C'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row around-xs">
    <div>
      <h4>Checkboxes:</h4>
      <div v-for="(item,index) in categories" :key="index">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="item.value" v-model="selected">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Multi-select (using same model):</h4>
      <select v-model="selected" multiple>
        <option :value="item.value" v-for="(item,index) in categories" :key="index">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>
    Result: {{ selected }}
  </h3>
</div>
```